# Aggregate and postpone function execution in Python

Tags: python

I have my own function in python which is called occasionally by some other code many times per second. My function looks like this:

```
def doIt(id):
    doSomething(id)
```

As a consequence doSomething() is called same number of times as doIt() and that is causing troubles. How can I aggregate calls of doIt(id) and call doSomething(id) only once 5 seconds after last call of doIt(id)? id parameter is variable and calling doIt(123) should have no effect on doIt(789)

Comment: Sounds like you want a Thread and/or to time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  If I'm reading this right, your problem is that someone could call `doIt(10)` multiple times in five seconds, but you'd only want `doSomething(10)` to be called once per five seconds.

In that case, you can do this without threads relatively easily; `doIt()` can remember when `doSomething()` was last called with certain arguments, and only call it again if it wasn't particularly recent.

```
import timeit

doSomething_calls = {}

def doIt(id):
    now = timeit.default_timer()  # wallclock time in seconds
    if id in doSomething_calls:
        if now - doSomething_calls[id] > 5:  # If the last real call was more than 5 seconds ago
            doSomething(id)  # Do a new call
            doSomething_calls[id] = now  # And update the time we last did a real call
    else:
        doSomething(id)
        doSomething_calls[id] = now
```

That function can be cut down significantly with judicious use of `{}.get()`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.  It's hard enough to learn without someone throwing everything at you at once.  :)

Alternatively, if you want the call to `doSomething(x)` to wait until there haven't been any calls to `doIt(x)` for 5 seconds, you'll need threads or subprocesses to avoid locking your program up while it waits.  Here's how you'd do that:

```
import threading
import time
import timeit

doIt_calls = {}

def doIt(id):
    doIt_calls[id] = timeit.default_timer()

def doSomethingThread():
    to_delete = []
    while alive:
        now = timeit.default_timer()
        for id, wallclock_time in doIt_calls.items():
            if now - wallclock_time > 5:  # If the last time `doIt(id)` was called was longer than 5s ago
                doSomething(id)  # Enact the `doSomething()` call
                to_delete.append(id)  # Remove the scheduled call from the dictionary so we don't immediately call it again next loop.
        for id in to_delete:
            del doIt_calls[id]
        time.sleep(0.1)

alive = True  # set this False after the end of your program to kill the thread

thread = threading.Thread(target=doSomethingThread)
thread.start()

# Rest of your program

alive = False  # Tell the thread to die after it's done with the current loop
```

Comment: This solution would work only if doIt(id) was called forever. Unfortunately it's called apx. 20x for only 2 seconds and then it's not called any more in near future. That is why I need doSomething(id) be called only once 5 seconds after last call of doIt(id)

Comment: My solution would call `doSomething()` once per 5 seconds at most, isn't that what you wanted?

Do you mean that `doSomething(x)` should be called 5 seconds after the _final_ call to `doIt(x)`?  In that case you will need threads to avoid locking up your program.  Let me know if that's the case and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, doSomething(x) should be called 5 seconds after the final call to doIt(x)

Comment: Had to change for loop to iterate in `doIt_calls.items()` to make it work but anyway I get RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Augh that's what I get for writing it from memory instead of the interactive interpreter.

Edited my answer again, for what _should_ be the last time.  :D